# Devise can't detect :omniauthable, but it's there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have a RoR application, running the Devise Gem for authentification. For my new API I've implemented the Gem "devise-token-auth": https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Since I want Devise to run for the website and API authentication, I followed the extra tips in the following instruction as well (and als the FAQ of the Gem's Git): http://www.developingandrails.com/2015/02/api-authentication-with-devisetokenauth.html

I've deactivated Devise's :confirmable, but activated :omniauthable. Everything seems to be in place, but I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/sebastianplasschaert/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:240:in `block in devise_for': Mapping omniauth_callbacks on a resource that is not omniauthable (ArgumentError)
Please add `devise :omniauthable` to the `User` model
```

And in my User model I start with the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

So, :omniauthable seems to be there. When I deactivate:

```
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

then everything works again (but I need it for my API authentication).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for some reason `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User` in removing the `omniauthable`.

I fixed the issue adding it back:

```
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
devise :omniauthable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @grabrielhilal. I already found that hack and tried it. It works fine for the api part, but it disables my sign up: I'm not able anymore to create a new account... Does signup still work in your case?

Comment: I'm working on that right now... you need to override the `OmniauthCallbacksController`, so you can create your user and then sign in using `sign_in(:user, @user, store: false, bypass: false)`

Comment: you can take some logic from here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/v0.1.36/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb